# how to get twitter account details when username of the account is know through a single request

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter

I am doing a web application where i get twitter user's username. At the same time when someone click on that name i want to show his account details with his profile picture of that twitter account. Does anybody has a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var url = "https://twitter.com/" + twitterUsername + "/profile_image?size=original";
 This works fine.